# Should Conway's Game of Life have an infinite map or should it be limited?

Tags: algorithm, rust, conways-game-of-life

I'm developing a Conway's implementation in Rust to further use it with WebAssembly, and I'm thinking about how I'm supposed to treat the map boundaries. At the moment, I'm considering a cell at the limits as a cell that has less neighbors, although I've seen some implementations that treat the map as infinite.

Treating the map with limited bounds generates some weird behaviour, like  a Glider becoming a Block:

```
------generation(0)------
0.0..
.00..
.0...
------generation(1)------
..0..
0.0..
.00..
------generation(2)------
.0...
..00.
.00..
------generation(3)------
..0..
...0.
.000.
------generation(4)------
.....
.0.0.
..00.
------generation(5)------
.....
...0.
..00.
------generation(6)------
.....
..00.
..00.
------generation(7)------
.....
..00.
..00.
```

Is the "right" way to treat the map as infinite as I saw [here](http://pmav.eu/stuff/javascript-game-of-life-v3.1.1/) or is the "right" way to limit the map? If there isn't any "right" way, which of those two you think that is the best?

If you'd like to see my code, it's [here](https://github.com/gabrielcarneiro97/Conways-Game-of-Life/blob/master/rust-module/src/main.rs). I didn't post any code sample because the question isn't about the code itself.

Comment: Asking for the *right* way to solve a task attracts opinionated answers, which is not encouraged at SO. That said, in my opinion you probably want a toroidal grid (one that wraps around on the edges), which is a pretty good approximation of an infinite grid if it is *large enough*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [rules for the Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#Rules) state (emphasis mine):

> The universe of the Game of Life is an **infinite two-dimensional orthogonal grid** of square "cells", each of which is in one of two possible states, alive or dead, (or "populated" and "unpopulated" respectively).

If you don't make your grid infinite, *you haven't implemented the Game of Life*, but rather you've implemented some variant.

Comment: Uhn, thanks for the answer, I'll adjust my code.